# Is there a way to sort records when using contract API and GetList?

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to return a list of the top 20 purchase orders sorted by number, desc. This seems like it should be easier than I'm finding it. Below is a sample of the code that grabs the top 100 records (although I'm not clear on what sort order this might be using)

```cs
Dim orders = soapClient.GetList(New PurchaseOrder With {
                .OrderNbr = New StringReturn(),
                .[Date] = New DateTimeSearch With {.Condition = DateTimeCondition.IsGreaterThan, .Value = "11/20/2018"},
                .RowNumber = New LongSearch With {.Condition = LongCondition.IsLessThan, .Value = 100},
                .VendorID = New StringSearch With {.Condition = StringCondition.Equal, .Value = "V1002"},
                .Status = New StringSearch With {.Condition = StringCondition.Equal, .Value = "OPEN"},
            .ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with GetList(), I've found that you cannot control the sorting in the GetList() call itself.  The sort order is based on the default for the entity involved.  As an example, doing a GetList() on the Stock Items causes the list to be sorted by InventoryID.  And for Purchase Orders, it is sorted by the OrdNumber.   If you create a Generic Inquiry and specify a sort order, then that will be used in your GetList() call to that GI.